# Is it possible to backup Windows / Linux clients using Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: backup, mac-mini, osx-server

We're investigating the use of a Mac Mini Server + NAS for a small office. I know Mac computers can be backed up by this setup. Is it also possible to backup Windows / Linux clients with such a setup?

If possible in a pull-manner: where the server would actively search and backup clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in a push configuration.  I am unaware of software that runs on OS X server and will scan Windows/Linux machines to pull backups.  Even OS X uses the time machine client installed on each Mac to push the backup to the server.